# can't find CONFIG_CRYPTO_ABLK_HELPER option in menuconfig

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

I am trying to activate the `CONFIG_CRYPTO_ABLK_HELPER` module while custamizing the 4.8 kernel. But after the search in `menuconfig` get the message:

```
Symbol: CRYPTO_ABLK_HELPER [=n]  
Type  : tristate                                   Defined at crypto/Kconfig:235 

Depends on:CRYPTO[=y]

Selects: CRYPTO_CRYPTD[=n]                                                         
Selected by: CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL [=n] && CRYPTO [=y] && X86 [=y]
CRYPTO_CAMELLIA_AESNI_AVX_X86_64 [=n] && X86 [=y] && 64B
```

I can not find my way to this option to activate it. Why isn't there the indications like fore most of those menus? Any idea?

Comment: I got my custom kernel 4.4 config below here :# cat config-4.4.0 | grep  CRYPTO_ABLK_HELPER 
CONFIG_CRYPTO_ABLK_HELPER=m
I set it as module. You can set it to yes.Kernel config will activate another dependencies module.When you do vi kernel config.You can find it on Crypto core or helper part.

Comment: Now, after I set the CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL to yes, I find also the CRYPTO_ABLK_HELPER [y]. It looks that the last got set to yes automaticaly after the first one was set to yes.

Comment: So you got it.Some modules will depend on another modules too.Like You installed some .deb/.rpm packages.Sorry , CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL=m. I didnt read it all.

Comment: Sorry,my own config was CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL=m. I didnt read it all.

Answer (score 0):

I got my custom kernel 4.4 config below here

```
:# cat config-4.4.0 | grep CRYPTO_ABLK_HELPER 

CONFIG_CRYPTO_ABLK_HELPER=m
```

I set it as moduler

```
# vi config-4.4.0

CONFIG_CRYPTO=y

#
 #  Crypto core or helper
#

CONFIG_CRYPTO_FIPS=y

CONFIG_CRYPTO_ALGAPI=y

CONFIG_CRYPTO_ALGAPI2=y

CONFIG_CRYPTO_AEAD=y

....
....

CONFIG_CRYPTO_MCRYPTD=m

CONFIG_CRYPTO_AUTHENC=m

CONFIG_CRYPTO_TEST=m

CONFIG_CRYPTO_ABLK_HELPER=m

CONFIG_CRYPTO_GLUE_HELPER_X86=m
```

Comment: I have difficulty to arrave to the point where I can make it M or Yes. The help in menuconfig doesn't give me the location of the option among the many menu lines. Thanks.

Comment: You can edit it and change it to m or y and save it.When you set it to m.You can load it anytime.When  you set it to y.Kernel will load it on boot. It wont cause any problem.You should set CONFIG_CRYPTO = y from menuconfig.

Comment: It seems to depend on many other options, so setting it manually like that probably won't enable it.